# Creating a searchable FAQ section in sharepoint 2010

Tags: 2010, web-part

How can i create a FAQ section that I can use a basic search web part to search through the FAQ and display the most relevant results.

I am new to sharepoint and need some guidance,
thanks.

Comment: I hope your are using a custom list or Discusion board for FAQ , if no what approch you are using to create FAQ. one more question is standered sharepoint serach if configure in your enviroment if yes, user can search for FAQ list item diretly and no need to tabke care about it.

Comment: I have the custom list with the two columns in newsletter style but what about adding in a search web part onto a separate page, how can i get that to search my faq?

For example a user can input a question into the search web part on the search page and that question will return the results most relevant to their search from the Q and A list; kind of like a google search

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to setup a FAQ in SharePoint is to use a custom list. I've written up a guide to doing this on my blog: http://thechriskent.com/2012/03/09/simple-sharepoint-faq-in-5-minutes/

To summarize:

1. Create a custom list. Name it FAQ or something.
2. Edit the Title column and rename it Question.
3. Add a new Column of type Multi-Line Text and name it Answer
4. Modify the default view to only show those 2 columns and set the style to Newsletter.

In order to search it, the search box at the top of the view page will default to just searching the list. So as long as a crawl has run, your items should show up. If you'd like to get fancier, you could specify a scope just for that list and add a custom search page.

Comment: This was a great suggestion!!! The only difference in my implementation is that I used the "Preview Pane" style on the list. Thanks for the tip!! :)